# Filtering Months with Criteria using AutoFitler (VBA)

Tags: excel, vba, date, criteria, autofilter

So theoretically, this concept for filtering dates by month should work, but it is not. I'm using a form that logs each assignment done, and then dates them with a standard format. I'm confused as to why this code is not working to count the dates in this form. Each month in the form will always be formated as x/xx/xxxx for single digit months, and xx/xx/xxxx for double digit months. In my mind, finding a cell that starts with the characters for each month and then counting them, should be a simple enough concept for my needs. The problem is that when it counts the rows based on this filter, it returns 0. Does anyone know what's going on?

Thanks!

```
 With iTable
        .AutoFilter
        .AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=tin
        .AutoFilter Field:=3, Criteria1:="=1/*"
        End With
        TData.Cells(i, 4).Value = iTable.Resize(, 1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Count - 1


        With iTable
        .AutoFilter
        .AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=tin
        .AutoFilter Field:=3, Criteria1:="=2/*"
        End With
        TData.Cells(i, 5).Value = iTable.Resize(, 1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Count - 1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get an accurate count per month, you could use an unused column to the right as a 'helper' column with the [MONTH function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/MONTH-function-579A2881-199B-48B2-AB90-DDBA0EBA86E8). This 'helper' column could be deleted after it has served its purpose as criteria for the [Range.AutoFilter Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff193884.aspx).

You could also write a quick [Conditional Formatting](https://support.office.com/en-au/article/Use-a-formula-to-apply-conditional-formatting-fed60dfa-1d3f-4e13-9ecb-f1951ff89d7f) on the dates in column C and apply the `Operator:=xlFilterCellColor` option to the .Autofilter on column C.

```
Option Explicit

Sub Macro2()
    Dim m As Long, n As Long, tin As String, vMNTHs As Variant

    vMNTHs = Array(1, 2)
    tin = "tin"

    With Worksheets("sheet3")
        If .AutoFilterMode Then .AutoFilterMode = False
        With .Cells(1, 1).CurrentRegion
            For m = LBound(vMNTHs) To UBound(vMNTHs)
                If .Parent.AutoFilterMode Then .Parent.AutoFilterMode = False
                With .Resize(.Rows.Count - 1, 1).Offset(1, 2)
                    .FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlExpression, Formula1:="=MONTH(C2)=" & vMNTHs(m)
                    .FormatConditions(.FormatConditions.Count).SetFirstPriority
                    .FormatConditions(1).Interior.Color = vbRed
                    .FormatConditions(1).StopIfTrue = True
                End With

                .AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=tin, Operator:=xlFilterValues
                .AutoFilter Field:=3, Criteria1:=vbRed, Operator:=xlFilterCellColor

                n = Application.Subtotal(102, Columns(3))
                MsgBox "the count for " & Format(DateSerial(2016, vMNTHs(m), 1), "mmmm") & " is " & n

                With .Resize(.Rows.Count - 1, 1).Offset(1, 2)
                    .FormatConditions(1).Delete
                End With
            Next m
        End With
        If .AutoFilterMode Then .AutoFilterMode = False
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you, I think this might be the answer. I'm already using a temporary tab with columns to sort my information. I didn't even think of the MONTH function!

Unfortunately, I wont be able to try this until Monday when I'm back in the office. I will keep you updated!

Comment: I was able to test a simpler version on my home computer, and it totally works! You are a lifesaver, thank you. What a simple fix!